# why in this piece of code, fgets returns null when it shouldn't?

Tags: c, file, debugging, fgets

I am coding a program that a piece of it is as below:

```
#define BUFFSIZE 2000
while( fgets(buff, BUFFSIZE - 1, fPtr) != NULL)
{
    //how many words is read from the source file in the current line
    int wordread = 0;

    word = strtok(buff, punc);
    //one word read
    while( word != NULL)
    {
        //sorting
        int k = 0;
        while(strcmp(word, words[k]) < 0)
            k++;
        if(strcmp(word, words[k]))
        {
            last++;
            for(int l = last; l >= 0; l--)
                strcpy(words[l + 1],words[l]);
            strcpy(words[wordread],word);
        }
        index[last][lineread]++;

        wordread++;//go to next word

        word = strtok(NULL, punc);
    }
    lineread++;//go to next line
}
```

but I understood that the compiler doesn't go inside the first while

```
while( fgets(buff, BUFFSIZE - 1, fPtr) != NULL)
```

I understood that this fgets returns NULL at first. but fPtr has an correct address and in the address there is a file of some data.

```
FILE *fPtr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

and the definition of buff is:

```
char buff[BUFFSIZE];
```

can anyone help? if the whole of the code is needed, tell me to write all of it.

Comment: End of the file? Read error? After the loop use e.g. [`feof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) and [`ferror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ferror) to check for these conditions.

Comment: See fget's reference:
If the end-of-file is encountered while attempting to read a character, the eof indicator is set (feof). If this happens before any characters could be read, the pointer returned is a null pointer (and the contents of str remain unchanged).
If a read error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a null pointer is also returned (but the contents pointed by str may have changed).
So you can check either feof or ferror to see what happened.

Comment: The compiler does not play a part when the program is *running*. You should learn to debug your own code; normally this is done using a tool called a *debugger* You should have one installed on your platform, for example if this is on linux and you use gcc to compile, you can use gdb to debug.

Comment: Can you check if there is such a file in that directory programmatically? Like `FILE *fPtr = fopen(argv[1], "r"); if(fPtr == NULL) perror(argv[1]); else {//Yourstuff}` By that you can see whether your program can find that directory and open that file.

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem maybe the title is improperly chose.Actually I debugged it and made a lot of time spotting that where the problem is located. I really don't understand why the code doesn't work

Comment: @MehmetSedatGüngör yeah actually I'd checked that. there's a correct address in fPtr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that the compiler didn't get into the first loop was the the file that it was supposed to read of, wasn't there. and It was returning `NULL`